# Powershell Extract ip's from string

Tags: string, powershell, ip, extract

I would like to get from the user 2 variables:
$ip1 
$ip2

and run a loop between their IP address. for example:

```
$ip1 = 192.168.1.10   
$ip2 = 192.168.1.200
```

The script assume its a class C, the i need to strip everything and get 3 variables:

```
$IP = 192.168.1.
$FirstIP = 10
$LastIp = 200
```

At first i thought about substring ($ip.length - 3), that could give me XXX, .XX, X.X (Where X is a number) Depends on the last Octat.. 
Any idea how can it be done nicely?

Comment: I personally like using -replace : `'192.168.1.100' -replace '\.\d+$'`

Comment: First: Thank you very much it works :), if its not trouble, can you translate to words what it means: '\.\d+$' ?

Comment: Yes. It is regex match for literal `.` (`\.`) and a digit (`\d`) one or more times (`+`) followed by end of string (`$`)

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string by dot and use range operator to create an array from last elements:

`$ip1.Split('.')[-1]..$ip2.Split('.')[-1] | foreach{$_}`